# Simple way to refresh a jsp page based on hibernate criteria update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I have a jsp page which shows all of my products, on the left hand side of the page there are various options to narrow down the selection similar to many online shops.  Example, user wants to limit results to price ranges similar to how Best Buy does it and I am using checkboxes to represent which criteria the user wants to be shown (it will default on first view to show all products).

In my jsp I have something like this

```
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"><i></i>$0 - $20</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"><i></i>$20 - $30</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"><i></i>$30 - $40</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"><i></i>$50+</label>
```

and here is what I have for my java controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/btwn", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView betweenCriteria(@RequestParam("min") double min, @RequestParam("max") double max){
    List<Product> productsBtwn = productService.findProductsBetween(min, max);
    return null;
}
```

When the user checks any one of the checkboxes I would like the page to refresh with only the selected criteria showing, so how do I get values (i.e a min and a max) back to my java controller so I can run a query to return a set with only the selected price range back to the user.

The closest thing I could get to was the use of @RequestParam annotations at my java controller, but where do those values go in my jsp and how should the endpoint (/btwn) be called?

Also I would like to avoid using javascript/jquery as I do not have much time, and the learning curve for those technologies seems too steep at this point, I am ok with page refreshing, will slowly migrate to ajax in the future.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for your controller just use `@PathVariable` [see docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/btwn/{min}/{max}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String btwn(@PathVariable() int min,@PathVariable() int max){

    // IF max == 0 ? true:false;
    max = max == 0 ? 100:max;

    List<Product> productsBtwn = productService.findProductsBetween(min, max);

    return "jspFile";
}
```

and for the jsp since your method type is GET i prefer to use `<a href=""></a>`

```
    <label class="checkbox"><a href="/btwn/0/20">$0 - $20</a></label>
    <label class="checkbox"><a href="/btwn/21/30">$21 - $30</a></label>
    <label class="checkbox"><a href="/btwn/31/40">$31 - $40</a></label>
    <label class="checkbox"><a href="/btwn/41/50">$41 - $50</a></label>
    <label class="checkbox"><a href="/btwn/51/0">$51+</a></label>
```

Comment: im glad that i was able to help